# When I try to choose a sepcific option from the menu I created it just outputs the menu again

Tags: python, loops, count, increment

For my class we were asked to create a menu with three options for a music organizer, the code below is a chunk from my entire code. Whenever I run the program I don't get errors, but when I type in 1, the terminal just shoots out the menu of options again instead of "Enter artists name:"

Any idea why?

# Create the menu of options

```
option = 0
while option != 3:

    print("What would you like to do?")
    print("  1. count all the songs by a particular artist")
    print("  2. print the contents of the database")
    print("  3. quit")
    option = int(input("Please enter 1, 2, or 3: "))
    # For option 1: find a all the songs on a certain album
    if option == 1:
        # Set the user input to a variable
        Artistname = str("Enter artist name: ")
        artistFound = False
        for i in range(len(artistList)):
            # For all the artist names in the list, compare the user input to #the artist names
            if artistList[i] == Artistname:
                artistFound = True
            # count songs associate with artist
                number+=1
                print(count, "songs by",artistList[i])
         # If the user input isn't in the list, then print out invalid
        if artistFound == false:
                print("Sorry, that is not an artist name")
```

Comment: please follow [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: avoid using indexes as much as you can. The whole artist-finding code can be reduced to `artistList.find(Artistname)` or `artistList.index(Artistname)`

Comment: where is `count` defined/assigned?

Answer (score 0):

try this for taking user input

```
Artistname =input("Enter artist name: ")
```

use break to get out of while loop or press 3

Comment: if you are using python2, that is

Comment: for python3 its input()

Comment: I am using python3.4, should I do something different with this version? I tried changing it to raw_input which got it out put "Enter artist name:", but when I try typing an artist in it outputs the menu again

Comment: my bad...i mean for python3 its input()....look at the line where you asked user to input choice

Comment: also since its not finding any artist and you have not used any break....it remains in while loop

Comment: print Artistname while give print Enter artist name:

Comment: I swapped it back to input (that's what I originally had) but now I am getting a string error

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
Artistname = str("Enter artist name: ")
```

binds the string `"Enter artist name: "` to the variable named `Artistname`, so your code is looking for items in `artistList` with the value `"Enter artist name: "` - which probably is not in the list.

The other problem is that in the line:

```
if artistFound == false:
```

`false` is not a valid identifier in Python. This should raise an exception, if it's not you might have assigned a value to `false`  elsewhere?

To fix the problem you need to get input from the user:

```
artist_name = input("Enter artist name: ")
```

Now `artist_name` will contain some value entered by the user and your search code will now be looking for something more likely to exist in the list.

Note that your search code can be reduced substantially by using [**`list.count()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

```
artist_name = input("Enter artist name: ")
artist_count = artist_list.count(artist_name)
if artist_count > 0:
    print('{} songs by {}'.format(artist_count, artist_name))
else:
    print("Sorry, that is not an artist name")
```